# how to display multiple data using ListView in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

On clicking Button ADD ANOTHER as in Screenshot 
It will add another medication after one another. So problem is that, I am unable to display the multiple data .

How can i show it using list view any help please.

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can easily just post your code to help it out easily.

Comment: No code , just need to know how to display all the data entered on button click in a listview.  In screen shot the Button in ADD ANOTHER and the elements are Name ,Taken As , and Next Visit  . @ReadyAndroid

Comment: just add another data in Model class and use notifydatasetchanged()

Answer (score 1):

Simply ,Add data in your ArrayList which you are passing in adapter constructor. After then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` .If you face problem with listview height ,then set it dynamically on button click -

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
if (listAdapter == null)
    return;

int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int totalHeight = 0;
View view = null;
for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
    if (i == 0)
        view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    view.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
}
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: I just want to show all the data on to the listview everytime i add items on clicking ADD ANOTHER  button .@Karandeep Atwal

Comment: yes this code do the same as you want.just  give a try